# Rewrite GuzzleHttp\Client in Magento2 not working

Tags: magento2, composer, php-7, magento-commerce

Though it is very basic or I suppose to have this working straight but after spending hours am looking for community experts insight/support.

Have to add monitoring of all outgoing requests from Magento Commerce 2.4.3 to any external services and all our platform services uses only `GuzzleHttp\Client`, so went through plugin and then preference way of adding the monitoring activities from `\[Company]\[Monitoring]\MF\HTTP\GuzzleClient` which overwrites or adds updates on top of parent `\GuzzleHttp\Client::request` method, the request is not falling to local namespace implementation but to vendor composer Guzzle module only.

Also tried adding `ps-4` file dependency rewrite`"GuzzleHttp\\Client": "app/code/[Company]/[Monitoring]/MF/HTTP/GuzzleClient"` in this case also I am not able to get it to load the local implementation.

Looking for help here, any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you cannot overwrite `\GuzzleHttp\Client` with Magento DI because it's may used without object manager and used as 3rd party library directly.

I see 2 options to cover your request

1. Use patch to library files and use `cweagans/composer-patches` or something similar. This means you create a patch for library file and apply it with composer during install.

   ```json
   {
       // ...
       "extra": {
           "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
           "patches": {
               "guzzlehttp/guzzle": {
                   "Description": "patches/guzzlehttp-guzzle.patch"
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   Place your patch into `patches/guzzlehttp-guzzle.patch` in git diff with base dir `vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle`

   Remember to run `composer install -v` to apply changes in patch after editing the `composer.json`.
2. Overwrite with composer autoload

   ```json
   {
       // ...
       "autoload": {
           // ...
           "exclude-from-classmap":[
               "vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Client.php"
           ],
           "files": [
               "app/code/[Company]/[Monitoring]/MF/HTTP/GuzzleClient.php"
           ]
       }
   }
   ```

   Remember that the namespace within your file needs to match original one `GuzzleHttp`

   Remember to run `composer dump-autoload` after editing the `composer.json`.

**[Update]**

If you want to allow to overwrite `GuzzleHttp\Client` with Magento DI you may use something like logic decorated in helper as example.

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Helper/HttpClient.php**

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Helper;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use GuzzleHttp\ClientFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;

class HttpClient extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected ClientFactory $clientFactory;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        ClientFactory $clientFactory
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->clientFactory = $clientFactory;
    }

    public function create(array $config = []): Client
    {
        return $this->clientFactory->create($config);
    }
}
```

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/etc/di.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="GuzzleHttp\Client" type="Acme\StackExchange\GuzzleHttp\Client"/>
    <type name="GuzzleHttp\Client">
        <plugin name="Acme_StackExchange_Plugin_GuzzleHttp_ClientPlugin"
                type="Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\GuzzleHttp\ClientPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Preference will work

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/GuzzleHttp/Client.php**

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\GuzzleHttp;

class Client extends \GuzzleHttp\Client
{
    // your customizations
}
```

Plugin will work

**app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Plugin/GuzzleHttp/ClientPlugin.php**

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\GuzzleHttp;

use GuzzleHttp\Client;

class ClientPlugin
{
    public function beforeRequestAsync(Client $subject, string $method, $uri = '', array $options = []): array
    {
        // your logic

        return [$method, $uri, $options];
    }
}
```